# Must I using fclose function?

Tags: php, fclose, file-pointer

When I open file :

```
$d = fgets(fopen("file.txt", "r"));
```

and I don't created file pointer, need I using fclose() ?

Comment: May depend on the language which you have not tagged...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add a tag with your language, also format your code as code (highlight your code then control + k)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like PHP.  Yes you must use `fclose()` which is why you also must use a variable to hold the file handle.

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r")
$data = fgets($handle);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Yes it works in the sense that you can read the file. But your file will remain open afterwards, which leaks a file descriptor. If you do this with too many files you will run into problems. Always try to code the 'right way', not the 'way that happens to work'.